# Is there some types based on condition in Scala?

Tags: scala

Imagine I have

```
val int_list : List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
val tuple_list : List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,4), (3,0))
```

And I want to choose `result_list` as one of them, based on condition:

```
val result_list = if (condition) int_list else tuple_list
```

Then if I choose one of the element

```
val first_element = result_list.head
```

it will have `Any` type. It seems logical, because it is the closest common parent to `Tuple2` and `Int` types. But am I able to set it type explicitly? Something like

```
type ResultType =  if (condition) Int else (Int, Int)
val result_list : List[ResultType] = if (condition) int_list else tuple_list
```

Or how can I implement such thing else how? I can of course refer to `int_list` or `tuple_list` but for now it seems to me that it will need to write `if (condition)` everywhere where it appears, which seems quite irrational.

P.S. I faced such thing when worked with graphs and result variable is list of neighbors of vertex. If graph is unweighted then it is `List[VertexId]`, else it is `List[(VertexId, Double)]` where `Double` represents cost of edge.

Comment: The condition is evaluated at runtime, as such this information is not available a compile-time. You may use a custom **ADT**, `Either`, union types or generics to overcome this situation, each of them has their own tradeoffs so is hard to recommend an alternative without more context.

Answer (score 2):

As @Luis elaborated in the comment, there are many options. One of them, is to use [Either](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html):

```
val int_list : List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
val tuple_list : List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,4), (3,0))

type IntOrTuple = Either[Int, Tuple2[Int, Int]]

val result_list : List[IntOrTuple] = if (Random.nextBoolean()) int_list.map(Left.apply) else tuple_list.map(Right.apply)
```

Another option you have, is to define a `trait Vertex`, and have there the common properties/methods/functions, and 2 implementations of it:

```
trait Vertex {
  // Actions you need
}

class VertexId extends Vertex {

}

object VertexId {
  def apply(ids: Int): VertexId = ???
}

class VertexWithCost extends Vertex

object VertexWithCost {
  def apply(ids: (Int, Int)): VertexWithCost = ???
}

val result_list: List[Vertex] = if (Random.nextBoolean()) int_list.map(VertexId.apply) else tuple_list.map(VerticesWithCost.apply)
```

Comment: It gives me for example `res0: IntOrTuple = Left(3)`. How can I work with it as `Int`? Or I need to do pattern matching everywhere?

Comment: @Nourless Either pattern matching, or using the API that `Either` offers, such as `fold`, `map`, etc... If you could elaborate what you are trying to achieve I might further assist.

Comment: I know there is something of chat here but I don't know how to use it properly

Comment: After several comments SO will suggest to create a chat room instead of having multiple comments.

Comment: In your update you write that both `apply` methods of `VertexId` and `VerticesWithCost` return `VertexId` typed value. The problem is that I need `VertexId` for unweighted and `(VertexId, Double)` for weighted case.

Comment: @Nourless `VertexId.apply` returns `VertexId`, and `VerticesWithCost.apply` returns `VerticesWithCost`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228518/discussion-between-tomer-shetah-and-nourless).